# How to display .active bootstrap pagination using jinja conditional?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to display `.active` on the current page, the client is.

I am using a `page` variable within a jinja conditional but I don't know how to get the current page to compare with and display the `.active` class as shown below.

```
 {% for page in pages %}
        {%if  page *****  %}
        <li class="page-item {{'active'}}">
          {%endif%}
          <a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('electronics', page=page, limit=limit) }}">{{ page }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

```
@app.route('/electronics/')
@app.route('/electronics/<page>/<limit>')
def electronics(page=1, limit=6):
    page=int(page)
    limit=int(limit)
    skip = page * limit - limit
    maximum = math.floor( (mongo.db.products.count_documents({})) / limit - 1)
    print(maximum)
    electronics = list(mongo.db.products.find({'category_name':"Electronics"}).sort("$natural", pymongo.DESCENDING).skip(skip).limit( limit ))
    return render_template(
        'electronics.html', 
        electronics=electronics,
        page=page,
        pages=range(1, int(maximum) + 1),
        maximum=maximum, 
        limit=limit
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `page` holds your current page and variable in a for loop overrides it. You can rename variable in for loop to e.g. `p` so that you can check if it equals `page`.

`electronics.html`:

```
{% for p in pages %}
    <li class="page-item{% if  p == page  %} active{% endif %}">
      <a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('electronics', page=p, limit=limit) }}">{{ p }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```